# PowerEdge R410 replace X5660 with E3-1270 v3

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

It's possible to replace a [X5660](http://ark.intel.com/products/47921/intel-xeon-processor-x5660-12m-cache-2_80-ghz-6_40-gts-intel-qpi) with a [E3-1270 v3](http://ark.intel.com/products/75056/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1270-v3-8M-Cache-3_50-GHz) in a PowerEdge R410?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The two processors are of different generations, use different physical motherboard sockets and totally different chipsets.

- X5660: LGA1366 (introduced with Nehalem - the original Core i7)
- E3-1270: LGA1150 (introduced with Haswell)

Check the "Package Specifications" section on the Intel pages you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can replace the mainboard **and** the CPU in order to to make the E3-1270 v3 work. But I won't recommend this at all.

The C5660 is quite old so warranty issues should not be a problem at all. But nevertheless you have to ensure that PSU and cooling can deal with the new setup. Besides this you have to ensure compatibility with peripheral devices and possibly also server managment.